# SignalR and SQLDependency Performance issues on Windows 8.1/IIS 8.5.9600.16384

Tags: asp.net, signalr, real-time, signalr-hub, sqldependency

I've just started working on a POC for implementing SignalR 2 + SQL Dependency for crating a real-time dashboard (though the POC I'm working is slight different then the project requirement).

This POC measures the CPU usage of server per logical core.

Preview of POC Test page

[image]

I've successfully implemented the Dependency preview and I can see real-time preview on a testing html page, the moment any changes made in my local SQL DB.

The changes are updated by a independent command line application, via a simple updated query. and my database is also having a 4 column simple single row structure (at least for now).

[image]

The problem is the CPU usage goes 95-100 percent after 20-30 changes triggered via 'dependency_OnChange' event *(Even when only Visual Studio and a single browser is open and command line application running for update)*.

Preview of after-shock

[image]

I'm using the Visual Studio (2015 Community Edition) in Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5. The POC page is run as "http://localhost:55725/index.html" and not hosted in IIS yet.

I tried solution depicted here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance

and also looked this thread for solution:
[SignalR & SqlDependency Query performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410204/signalr-sqldependency-query-performance)

I don't know yet, no fancy stuff yet (Will implement under Asp.Net MVC if performance is great), But no luck with even simplest dumb thing.

Code for Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDependency.Start(connString);
}

protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
}
```

Code for Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Code for Hub Class

```
public class AppHub : Hub
    {
        private static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ToString();

        [HubMethodName("sendMessages")]
        public static void SendMessages()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AppHub>();
            context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
        }
    }
```

Code for Testing html page (index.html):

```
<head>
    <script src="http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var notifications = $.connection.appHub;
            //debugger;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
                //alert("connection updated.")
                getAllMessages()

            };

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                //alert("connection started")
                getAllMessages();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        });


        function getAllMessages() {
            var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/appdata.ashx',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).success(function (result) {
                //                tbl.empty().append(result);
                DrawGauges(result);
            }).error(function () {

            });
        }

        function DrawGauges(jsondata) {
            var opts = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                angle: 0.15, // The length of each line
                lineWidth: 0.44, // The line thickness
                pointer: {
                    length: 0.9, // The radius of the inner circle
                    strokeWidth: 0.035, // The rotation offset
                    color: '#000000' // Fill color
                },
                limitMax: 'false',   // If true, the pointer will not go past the end of the gauge
                colorStart: '#9BF0E9',   // Colors
                colorStop: '#61D2D6',    // just experiment with them
                strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',   // to see which ones work best for you
                generateGradient: true
            };

            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

                var target = document.getElementById('canvas' + i); // your canvas element
                var textlabel = document.getElementById('text' + i); // your canvas element
                var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!

                gauge.maxValue = 100; // set max gauge value
                gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
                gauge.set(jsondata[0]["Core" + i + "Usage"]); // set actual value
                textlabel.innerText = jsondata[0]["Core" + i + "Usage"];
            }

        }
    </script>
    <style>
        h4 {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
            font-size:27pt;
        }
        span{
            position:relative;
            left:-12%;
            top:-75px;
            font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
            font-size:14pt;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h4>CPU Usage Per Core</h4>
            <div id="realtimepreview">
                <canvas width="300" height="120" id="canvas1"></canvas><span id="text1"></span>
                <canvas width="300" height="120" id="canvas2"></canvas><span id="text2"></span>
                <canvas width="300" height="120" id="canvas3"></canvas><span id="text3"></span>
                <canvas width="300" height="120" id="canvas4"></canvas><span id="text4"></span>
            </div>
```

Code for ASPX generic Handler - Invoked by client per request

```
public class AppData : IHttpHandler
        {

            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                CPUUsageHistory _messageRepository = new CPUUsageHistory();
                context.Response.Write(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_messageRepository.GetAllMessages()));
            }

            public bool IsReusable
            {
                get
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Code for SQL Dependency

```
        public class CPUUsage
        {
            public string Core1Usage { get; set; }
            public string Core2Usage { get; set; }
            public string Core3Usage { get; set; }
            public string Core4Usage { get; set; }
        }

    public class CPUUsageHistory
    {
        readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString;

        public IEnumerable<CPUUsage> GetAllMessages()
        {
            var cpuusage = new List<CPUUsage>();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Core1Usage],[Core2Usage],[Core3Usage],[Core4Usage]  FROM [dbo].[CpuUsageDetails]", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        cpuusage.Add(item: new CPUUsage
                        {
                            Core1Usage = reader["Core1Usage"].ToString(),
                            Core2Usage = reader["Core2Usage"].ToString(),
                            Core3Usage = reader["Core3Usage"].ToString(),
                            Core4Usage = reader["Core4Usage"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
            return cpuusage;


        }
        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                AppHub.SendMessages();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am missing/doing wrong?

Comment: With 2 -3 browser instance (Mostly Chrome 48)... System chocks and FireFox 45b crashed if used along with.

Answer (score 0):

Few things that you can do

1. Delay the update query performed by your command line tool to avoid frequent updates. E.g. wait for at least 200 Milliseconds before executing the update query. If within those 200 Milliseconds, there is any new updates then ignore the previous timer and reset it again for 200 MS. I understand that this workaround may not be suitable for your application because it is adding delay of 200 MS to update clients instead of being realtime.
2. Why don't you directly communicate with the HUB whenever there is any change in the SQL DB.  I mean the command line tool can directly provide the updates to the HUB instead of HUB getting information from SqlDependency change event.

Comment: 1. I did checked that option. 2. I'll check the hub-update option soon.